# Wrap text onto next line if no more space

Tags: html, css

I have this tooltip when hovering over the info icon next to the header. I can't make it wrap text to the next line if there's not enough space to display all of it. I've tried so many different versions of white-space and line-break I've run out of ideas.

On top of that IE doesn't display full width at all. I don't want to give my div a fixed width. I want it to dynamically wrap when there's no more space in the parent.

My desired result would be something like that in both IE and Chrome
[image]

```css
.info-tooltip {
  position: relative;
  display: inline;
  top: 1px;
  cursor: default;
  white-space: pre;
}

.info-tooltip:before {
  content: url("https://image.flaticon.com/icons/svg/685/685815.svg");
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  display: inline-block;
}

/* Tooltip text */
.info-tooltip .info-tooltip-text {
  visibility: hidden;
  background-color: #0BC6DD;
  color: #fff;
  border-radius: 4px;
  font-size: 14px;

  /* Position the tooltip text */
  position: absolute;
  top: 37px;
  left: -50px;
  display: table;
  z-index: 1;
  padding: 8px 8px 4px 8px ;

  /* Fade in tooltip */
  opacity: 0;
  transition: opacity 0.3s;
  -webkit-transition: opacity 0.3s;
  -moz-transition: opacity 0.3s;
  -ms-transition: opacity 0.3s;
  -o-transition: opacity 0.3s;
  transition: opacity 0.3s;
}

/* Tooltip arrow */
.info-tooltip .info-tooltip-text::after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 100%;
  left: 60px;
  margin-left: -5px;
  border-width: 5px;
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: transparent transparent #0BC6DD transparent;
}

/* Show the tooltip text when you mouse over the tooltip container */
.info-tooltip:hover .info-tooltip-text {
  visibility: visible;
  opacity: 1;
}

.info-tooltip .info-tooltip-text p {
  padding-bottom: 4px;
  margin: 0;
  font-weight: 100;
}
```

```html
<h1>There is a tooltip next to me <i class="info-tooltip"/>
  <div class="info-tooltip-text">
    <p>This is the actual tooltip to be displayed. A bit longer than expected. Should wrap where necessary.</p>
  </div>
</i></h1>
```

Answer (score 0):

added

```
width: 250px;
white-space: normal;
```

to `.info-tooltip .info-tooltip-text p`

```css
.info-tooltip {
  position: relative;
  display: inline;
  top: 1px;
  cursor: default;
  white-space: pre;
}

.info-tooltip:before {
  content: url("https://image.flaticon.com/icons/svg/685/685815.svg");
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  display: inline-block;
}


/* Tooltip text */

.info-tooltip .info-tooltip-text {
  visibility: hidden;
  background-color: #0BC6DD;
  color: #fff;
  border-radius: 4px;
  font-size: 14px;
  /* Position the tooltip text */
  position: absolute;
  top: 37px;
  left: -50px;
  display: table;
  z-index: 1;
  padding: 8px 8px 4px 8px;
  /* Fade in tooltip */
  opacity: 0;
  transition: opacity 0.3s;
  -webkit-transition: opacity 0.3s;
  -moz-transition: opacity 0.3s;
  -ms-transition: opacity 0.3s;
  -o-transition: opacity 0.3s;
  transition: opacity 0.3s;
}


/* Tooltip arrow */

.info-tooltip .info-tooltip-text::after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 100%;
  left: 60px;
  margin-left: -5px;
  border-width: 5px;
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: transparent transparent #0BC6DD transparent;
}


/* Show the tooltip text when you mouse over the tooltip container */

.info-tooltip:hover .info-tooltip-text {
  visibility: visible;
  opacity: 1;
}

.info-tooltip .info-tooltip-text p {
  padding-bottom: 4px;
  margin: 0;
  font-weight: 100;
  width: 250px;
  white-space: normal;
}
```

```html
<h1>There is a tooltip next to me <i class="info-tooltip" />
  <div class="info-tooltip-text">
    <p>This is the actual tooltip to be displayed. A bit longer than expected. Should wrap where necessary.</p>
  </div>
  </i>
</h1>
```

Comment: I want a div to expand nicely if the screen is large enough to display the whole message. I don't want it to be fixed 250px.